# Combo box listing latest 2 folders from path

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am quite new to VBA as I have been using other programming languages.

I am trying to use a combo box to list the latest 2 folders from my path.

I have already been able to select all data from the required path as well as I have sorted this.

I need support to be able to list only the latest 2 folders based on my code but am struggling and require help.

```
Drivepath = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1, 2)
On Error Resume Next
filepath = Drivepath & "C:\Users\Documents\Month\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.Value & "\"

Application.Workbooks.Open (filepath & s_workbook)

Application.Sheets(1).Activate


Dim name
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.Clear
Drivepath = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1,2)

For Each name In ListDirectory(Path:=Drivepath & "C:\Users\Documents\Month”, AttrInclude:=vbDirectory, AttrExclude:=vbSystem Or vbHidden)
    If Len(name) > 4 Then
        If InStr(name, "list") = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.AddItem name
    End If
Next name

'Sort the list

ComBoList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.List

For X = LBound(ComBoList) To UBound(ComBoList) - 1
    For j = X + 1 To UBound(ComBoList)
        If ComBoList(X, 0) > ComBoList(j, 0) Then
            ComBoTemp = ComBoList(X, 0)
            ComBoList(X, 0) = ComBoList(j, 0)
            ComBoList(j, 0) = ComBoTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next X

hold_name = ComBoList(UBound(ComBoList), 0)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.List = ComBoList
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Months"). ComboBox1.Value = hold_name

ListDirectory
```

`ListDirectory` function

```
Function ListDirectory(Path As String, AttrInclude As VbFileAttribute, Optional AttrExclude As VbFileAttribute = False) As Collection

    Dim Filename As String

    Dim Attribs As VbFileAttribute
    Set ListDirectory = New Collection
    ' first call to Dir() initializes the list

    Filename = Dir(Path, AttrInclude)
    While Filename <> ""
        Attribs = GetAttr(Path & Filename)

        ' to be added, a file must have the right set of attributes

        If Attribs And AttrInclude And Not (Attribs And AttrExclude) Then

            If Len(Filename) > 4 And InStr(Filename, "Oracle") = 0 Then 
                ListDirectory.Add Filename, Path & Filename
            End If

        ' fetch next filename

        Filename = Dir

    Wend

End Function
```

Am using sorting to sort the folders as all the required folders are named the following. E.g, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201904, 201905 and etc.

I just need a solution for selecting the last 2 folders which are 202003 & 202004.

I could easily delete all the other folders from the path but am looking for a more efficient way to only display 2 of the latest folders in the combo box.

Again, I have already sorted them but once I sorted them I would like to display or select only the latest folders based on sorting them.

Comment: Have you code for the ListDirectory routine ?

Comment: Tin, I have now added the listdirectory code.

Comment: How are you defining "Latest" ... Latest creation date for the folder, or the folders with the most recently modified files ?

Comment: Am using sorting to sort the folders as all the required folders are named the following. E.g, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201904, 201905 and etc. I just need a solution for selecting the last 2 folders which are 202003 & 202004. I could easily delete all the other folders from the path but am looking for a more efficient way to only display 2 of the latest folders in the combo box. Again, I have already sorted them but once I sorted them I would like to display or select only the latest folders based on sorting them.

Comment: You have them all in an array and you've sorted them - just select the last 2 elements of the array UBound() and UBound()-1  and add only those to the ComboBox ?

Comment: Sorry, how do I add these to the combobox so it only displays 2 folders instead of them all. For example once the path will be updated next month I will expect it to display 202005 & 202006.

Comment: Posted as an answer 3 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

```
K = UBound(ComboList)
TwoNewest = ComboList(K) & vbcrlf & ComboList(K-1)
ComboBox1.List = split(TwoNewest,vbcrlf)
```

There my be better ways but that'll work

Comment: When trying this the sort no longer works do you know how I can incorporate this into my code so it pulls through the latest 2 folders. Thank You

Comment: What do you mean it no longer works ? Did it crash, what was the error message, what line did it crash on, etc etc a lot more detail needed

Comment: After that, what have you tried to fix it & why, when you tried it what happened where have you placed Stops for debugging, what variables have you checked at what point, what values were showing ?

Comment: I have incorporated the above code within my sort statements where I Previously sorted the number of months. However, once adding this code my combobox is no longer sorted like what I did previously. Instead it list all the months folders in different orders. For example 201809 shows after 202005 etc. I just need away to incorporate this code so I am able to display 2 of the latest folders within the combobox.

Comment: If you modify your question and upload just the short section of code with my few lines (which I hope you have amended slightly) and show me 1 or 2 lines before and after my code that will help

Comment: The problem is that I removed the sorting code and replaced it with this piece of code as I don’t really know where the code goes that’s my issue. Could you help me if possible. Thank you

Comment: Ok, this is a coding forum, so you need to be able to do the very simplest of coding tasks and adding 3 lines of code into your existing code is not expecting too much of you.I have given you the answer, all that remains is for you to figure out where it goes within a mere 26 lines of code - so only 26 places to try it. Good luck